# jtableuser: :store failed in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I don't have any problem registering an user from frontend and activating a user from the email link

But, when Administrator tried to enable/disable a user i'm getting this weird error

**jtableuser: :store failed
Unknown column 'resetCount' in 'field list'**

I understood that resetCount filed was missing from the table structure and altered the table accordingly and this issue was solved

Can anyone tell me why/where this error came from ??
is there any newly added module/extension triggering this resetCount ??

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two new fields need to be added into the users table. Go to Extension Manager and click Database. You will probably see a message that the database structure is not uptodate. Click Fix in the top right hand corner and that should update the users table.